# SQL Server Management Studio - tool to change abbreviation to full table names

Tags: sql-server, keyboard-shortcuts

Im running SQL Server 2005. I was wondering if there is a tool our there that would allow to to say something like:

```
SELECT top 10 *
FROM ct
```

And the `ct` will be converted to `CustomerTable`

It does not have to be a SQL Server add on, could just be a windows app.
I just find that I keep calling the same tables many times over, and even though I have SQL Complete to autocomplete, it still takes a while to get the full table name out of it.

Comment: you need to create synonyms in data base..

Comment: You could create some snippets in your SQL Complete tool, maybe in Options

Comment: it could be possible but you have to create at your own using a lot of programming language.

Comment: why make it so difficult? Think about the maintainability if some 'magic' converts table names. Just use an alias which can be used in the query iteself: select top 10 ct.* FROM CustomerTable as ct